# Unable to install php7.2-curl on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu-16.04

I’m currently running Ubuntu 16.04 and I try to install php7.2-curl.

I running :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl
```

Result :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-curl
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2-curl'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-curl'
```

My php -v :

```
PHP 7.2.12-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Nov 12 2018 09:55:12) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.12-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

My /etc/apt/sources.list :

```
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial universe
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial universe
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-updates universe
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-updates universe
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial multiverse
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

I don’t understand why…

Comment: did you find any solution to this? is happening the same for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [ondrej/php](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) repository

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl`

Comment: Unfortunately that's what I'm already doing.

Comment: @AurélienW Did you find any solution to this ? I am facing the same issue. And unfortunately can't update my VM to ubuntu 18 from 16. So, if you get some solution for this, let me know. Thanks.